# CollectionVIew in TableViewCell in section swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, tableview

I have TableViewController with 7 sections and each sections have 1 row.

In 7th section need put CollectionView with UIImageView.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My code below. User have 9 images, but they don't display.

```
class NewDetailPhotographerTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    // loading data for display in view
}

extension NewDetailPhotographerTableViewController {

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let photo = photographer {
            switch section {
            case 1:
                return photo.photoShootingStyle.isEmpty ? 0 : 1
            case 2:
                return photo.languages.isEmpty ? 0 : 1
            case 3:
                return photo.equipment.isEmpty ? 0 : 1
            case 5:
                return photo.biography.isEmpty ? 0 : 1
            case 6:
                return photo.images.isEmpty ? 0 : 1
            default:
                return 1
            }
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}

extension NewDetailPhotographerTableViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photographer?.images.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "imagesCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! NewDetailPhotographerCollectionViewCell
        cell.imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: photographer!.images[indexPath.item]))
        return cell
    }
}

class NewDetailPhotographerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

class NewDetailPhotographerCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

In screenshot visible 6 sections, because 7th is invisible.

Storyboard screenshot are included.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you setting the delegate / dataSource for the collectionView? Are those funcs being called?

Comment: In storyboard to UITableViewCell

Comment: I would bet that's the issue. Try removing that from the storyBoard and try setting the dataSource and delegate in the tableviewDelegate call backs. For example in `cellForRow` or `willDisplayCell`. Also be sure to set dataSource and delegate back to nil in `prepareForReuse' of the tableViewCell. That should do it.